Trying to improve my SQL performance cost, index is not being used
I'm trying to optimize the performance of a SQL query by creating an index on one or more columns, but it seems that the index is not being used as expected. The query is still performing a full table scan. I am using Oracle database.
I’m looking to reduce the cost of the query. In the explain plan, many of the joins are using full table scans, which is significantly impacting performance. Our most recent attempt resulted in the query running for an hour on the server.
My select is build like this:
INSERT INTO VM_PEDIDO
  SELECT * 
  FROM V_PEDIDO_V1 
  WHERE CD_TIPONOTA NOT IN ('190','308','6090');

The explain plan is this:
| Id | Operation                       | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes  | Cost  | Time    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0  | SELECT STATEMENT                |                              | 22760 | 24M    | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 1  | HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                              | 22760 | 24M    | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 2  | VIEW                            | V_ITEM_MASCARA                | 5534  | 1432K  | 41    | 00:00:01|
| 4  | TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | ETL_V_ITEM_MASCARA_CONS    | 3697  | 108K   | 27    | 00:00:01|
| 5  | INDEX RANGE SCAN                | ETL_V_ITEM_MASCARA_CONS_INDEX1 | 3697 |        | 7     | 00:00:01|
| 6  | TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | ETL_V_ITEM_MASCARA_BASE    | 1837  | 58784  | 14    | 00:00:01|
| 7  | INDEX RANGE SCAN                | ETL_V_ITEM_MASCARA_BASE_INDEX2 | 1837 |        | 4     | 00:00:01|
| 8  | HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                              | 9990  | 8253K  | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 9  | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_TAB_ICMS                | 11760 | 149K   | 17    | 00:00:01|
| 10 | HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                              | 9990  | 8126K  | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 11 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_ITEM_PESO_CONS         | 3728  | 22368  | 5     | 00:00:01|
| 12 | HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                              | 9990  | 8068K  | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 13 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_PRODUTO                 | 347   | 3123   | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 14 | HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                              | 9990  | 7980K  | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 15 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_PRODSEMFARDO            | 29    | 203    | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 16 | HASH JOIN                       |                              | 9990  | 7912K  | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 17 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_PRODUTOS                | 13294 | 363K   | 25    | 00:00:01|
| 18 | HASH JOIN                       |                              | 9990  | 7638K  | 231K  | 00:00:10|
| 19 | HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                              | 66    | 34386  | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 20 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_FORMA_PGTO              | 825   | 9075   | 4     | 00:00:01|
| 21 | HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                              | 66    | 33660  | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 22 | HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                              | 6     | 3024   | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 23 | HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                              | 6     | 2844   | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 24 | HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                              | 6     | 2772   | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 25 | HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                              | 5     | 2250   | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 26 | JOIN FILTER CREATE              | :BF0000                      | 5     | 795    | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 27 | MERGE JOIN OUTER                |                              | 5     | 795    | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 28 | SORT JOIN                       |                              | 5     | 735    | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 29 | VIEW                            | V_PEDIDO                     | 5     | 735    | 227K  | 00:00:09|
| 30 | UNION-ALL                       |                              |       |        |       |         |
| 31 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_PEDIDO_CONS            | 4     | 324    | 216K  | 00:00:09|
| 32 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_PEDIDO_BASE            | 1     | 77     | 11034 | 00:00:01|
| 33 | FILTER                          |                              |       |        |       |         |
| 34 | SORT JOIN                       |                              | 1     | 12     | 4     | 00:00:01|
| 35 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | VM_CAD_PEDI_JUROS            | 1     | 12     | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 36 | VIEW                            |                              | 46    | 13386  | 7     | 00:00:01|
| 37 | HASH GROUP BY                   |                              | 46    | 736    | 7     | 00:00:01|
| 38 | VIEW                            | V_BLOQ_CREDITO               | 46    | 736    | 6     | 00:00:01|
| 39 | JOIN FILTER USE                 | :BF0000                      |       |        |       |         |
| 40 | UNION-ALL                       |                              |       |        |       |         |
| 41 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_BLOQ_CREDITO_CONS      | 42    | 630    | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 42 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_BLOQ_CREDITO_BASE      | 4     | 60     | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 43 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_DESCONTO_CLIENTE        | 624   | 7488   | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 44 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_GRUPOCLI                | 2602  | 31224  | 5     | 00:00:01|
| 45 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_CLIENTES2               | 33325 | 976K   | 77    | 00:00:01|
| 46 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TAUX_TIPOFRETE               | 52    | 312    | 3     | 00:00:01|
| 47 | VIEW                            | V_ITEM_PEDIDO_V2             | 1524K | 380M   | 4629  | 00:00:01|
| 48 | UNION-ALL                       |                              |       |        |       |         |
| 49 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_ITEM_PEDIDO_V2_CONS    | 14    | 149    | 5     | 00:00:01|
| 50 | TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ETL_V_ITEM_PEDIDO_V2_BASE    | 655   | 6332   | 16    | 00:00:01|

I guess the main cost is being produced in line 31.
I tried to create a indexes like this:
CREATE INDEX idx_cd_tiponota_check ON V_PEDIDO_V1 (
    CASE 
        WHEN CD_TIPONOTA IN ('190', '308', '6090') THEN NULL
        ELSE CD_TIPONOTA
    END
);

and this:
CREATE INDEX idx_cd_tiponota_check ON ETL_V_PEDIDO_BASE(CODTIPONOTA)

this is where i guess is the highest cost:


It looks like you forgot to include the definition of the view

Hello, Is the column number or varchar2 ?

Do you have a function-based index on TRIM(CODPERDIDO)?

NULL values are not stored in 1 column indexes.

@PetrBarandovski it is VARCHAR2

An index is nice but the database will still decide for itself if it should use it. If your SELECT statement needs to retrieve a substantial percentage of rows the database may decide that using a full table scan is quicker than using the index. Maybe you could add your view definition to the question as well as the sizes of the respective tables (and the percentage of rows you want to retrieve) which may give us more insight in this.
